# django @swagger_auto_schema properties

Tags: django, swagger, schema, auto

I want to put this response in swagger doc too! I use drf_yasg app in django. I've written this code:

```
@swagger_auto_schema(method='post', request_body=openapi.Schema(
        type=openapi.TYPE_OBJECT,
        properties={
                'login_id': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING, description='ID'),
                'password': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING, description='password'),
        }
))
```

The current swagger_auto_schema property is

```
{
   "login_id": "admin",
   "password": "1234",
}
```

I want to make swagger_auto_schema in the format below

```
{
"User": {
    "login_id": "admin",
    "password": "1234",
   }
}
```

I don't know how to provide json data

Comment: What do you mean by "provide JSON data"?

Comment: The current swagger_auto_schema property is
{
"login_id": "admin",
"password": "1234",
}
I want to make swagger_auto_schema in the format below
{
"User": {
"login_id": "admin",
"password": "1234",
}
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the `"User"` wrapper explicitly in your schema:

```
@swagger_auto_schema(method='post', request_body=openapi.Schema(
        type=openapi.TYPE_OBJECT,
        properties={
                'User': openapi.Schema(
                        type=openapi.TYPE_OBJECT,
                        properties={
                                'login_id': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING, description='ID'),
                                'password': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING, description='password'),
                        }
                )
        }
))
```